# Try-with transfer ownership

Tags: java, exception, try-with-resources

In Java 7, there is a try-with syntax that ensures objects like InputStream are closed in all code paths, regardless of exceptions.  However, the variable declared in the try-with block ("is") is final.

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("1.txt")) {
    // do some stuff with "is"
    is.read();

    // give "is" to another owner
    someObject.setStream(is);

    // release "is" from ownership: doesn't work because it is final
    is = null;
}
```

Is there a concise syntax to express this in Java? Consider this exception-unsafe method. Adding the relevant try/catch/finally blocks would make the method much more verbose.

```
InputStream openTwoFiles(String first, String second)
{
    InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream("1.txt");

    // is1 is leaked on exception
    InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("2.txt");

    // can't use try-with because it would close is1 and is2
    InputStream dual = new DualInputStream(is1, is2);
    return dual;
}
```

Obviously, I can have the caller open both files, placing them both in a try-with block. This is only one example of a case where I want to perform some operation on a resource before transferring ownership of it to another object.

Comment: Why do you need to release `is`? It specifically scoped for try block only.

Comment: try-with can never help in your situation.  The try-with is intended to be used in a situation where the identified resource must never persist outside the scope of the try block.  This in no way applies to your situation

Answer (score 1):

The try-with is intended to be used in a situation where the identified resource must never persist outside the scope of the try block.

If you want to use the try-with construction, you must change your design as follows:

1. Delete the `openTwoFiles()` method.  it is value free.
2. Create a constructor for the `DualInputStream` class that takes two file names and creates the two `InputStreams`.  Declare that this constructor throws `IOException` and allow it to throw `IOExceptions`.
3. Use the new constructor in a try-with construct.

Comment: The openTwoFiles method is an example. If I had the DualInputStream constructor accept file names, then I would still have all of my exception safety problems in the constructor implementation.

Comment: there is no exception safety problem in the constructor.  any IOException will excape the constructor and the object will be cleaned up.  you will not catch exceptions in the constructor.

Comment: That is untrue. If I opened two InputStream in the DIS constructor and an exception occurred when opening the second stream, the first stream would be leaked unless I wrote lengthy and verbose code to handle the case.